# In Adventurers League, can you finish a module you started if you leveled out of it?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, character-advancement, experience-points, dnd-adventurers-league

Here's a situation: Bob plays a 4 hours Adventurers League Tier 2 adventure with a level 10 character, but due to unforeseen time constraints, the module cannot be completed (only 3 hours in, for example). The end of that module is rescheduled for the following week. In the meanwhile, Bob plays another Tier 2 adventure which gives him enough experience points to go to level 11, therefore being considered a Tier 3 player.

While normally, Bob could not start the first Tier 2 adventure as he has now out-tiered it, can he still join the "wrap-up" session considering he had started the adventure in the right Tier? (in this situation, we assume that Bob refrains from playing Tier 3 adventures until he *possibly* completes his started Tier 2 adventure)

The AL FAQ says this:

> XP is applied immediately upon receiving it, and if it advances you to another level, you do so at the end of the session or the next long rest—whichever happens first. As a general rule, you can’t postpone applying in order to participate in a later adventure. Once you hit the threshold needed to advance to 5th level, for example, that character is no longer able to participate in level 1-4 adventures.

However, I think that the word participate here refers to starting an adventure, not finishing an already started one. Perhaps I missed another relevant section of the FAQ and/or Player/DM guide...

Similar situation to the above example: the experience points gotten before the module is stopped (to be completed the following week) would put Bob to the next Tier.

Other similar situation: Bob would do a long rest during the adventure, getting the XP from the monsters he defeated during the adventure before the rest, therefore advancing to the next level as per the FAQ.

Comment: Is this two different questions? you leveled up during and adventure and no longer qualify; and you leveled in another adventure between sessions?

Comment: I mean, they have the same consequence and come from the same rule, so I don't see the point in having two separate questions for it.

Answer (score 6):

## No.

**tl;dr** Once the character has leveled out, they can make a new character or use a pre-generated to continue the module.

The quote in the question about no longer being able to participate is correct, and the use of participation is in line with the vernacular use.

[participate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/participate):

> Be involved; take part.

### Leveling Between Sessions.

Being ineligible due to interim adventures appears to be a likely enough scenario that the DDAL warns about this case explicitly.

DDAL [FAQ](http://dndadventurersleague.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/DDAL-FAQ-v3.0.pdf) page 12:

> Players taking their characters from game to game
> in this way are permitted to advance in level, and
> earn rewards (gold, magic items, etc.) between
> sessions of a multiple-session adventure, but must
> exercise caution or else **they may accidently level out of their original game.**

### Leveling Intra-session.

While less likely than advancement between sessions situation, the rules on page 3 of the DDAL FAQ do cover both situations.  Once the character is outside the level range, they cannot participate.

DDAL [FAQ](http://dndadventurersleague.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/DDAL-FAQ-v3.0.pdf) page 3:

> Players that have characters outside the adventure’s
> level range cannot participate in the adventure with
> those characters. If you’re playing a tier one (levels 1 –
> 4) adventure, **players with ineligible characters can
> make a new 1st-level character or use a pregen.**

### Does Not Apply to Hard Cover Adventures

The above rules doe not apply to hard cover adventures.  Those do have their own restrictions such as a character can only be playing in one at a time.

> Hardcover Adventures
>
> These adventures typically use the following ranges
> and can be played by characters of a higher level,
> provided they are within the adventure’s level range
> when they begin playing the adventure.

Comment: So let's say you are at 84 000 xp (level 10), kill 1000 xp worth of creatures then do a long rest inside the module you're playing, it would then be impossible for you to complete it ? So you would have to leave the table ? And what if you were only three players at that table: you must leave due to having taken a long rest and leveling out, and then they aren't AL legal anymore because they're only 2 players so they can't complete the module either ?

Comment: @GaelL Haven't considered that.  I think that would make a good separate question.

Comment: Well it's kind of the same deal : you start something, you level out of it (either because the session ends before the module's planned end or because you take a long rest), and then... oopsies ?

Comment: I would add that this is not true for HCs.

Comment: @GaelL Very few DDAL modules allow for a short rest during the module, let alone a long rest. Also, the very possibility of the situation goes away in a few weeks with the change over to checkpoint advancement.

Comment: This part "a character can only be playing in one at a time." is kinda ambiguous here. You can "hop" between HC adventures as you want, you simply won't be able to come back later if you leveled out the range of the one you are not "playing" atm.